# How to ensure objects are not spawned on top of one another (random spawn location)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating an endless jumping game. I have created a lot of obstacles to spawn randomly for time and for spaces, but now I want to make the obstacles spawn not in the same place as the previous ones, because they are spawning but sometimes they can spawn on the top of the other or near the others or even inside them, so please help me!
code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnObstacles : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] Obstacle;
    public float MINTObstacle;
    public float MAXTObstacle;
    public bool spawning = false;
    public Transform pos;
    void Update()
    { 
        if (!spawning) 
        {
            StartCoroutine("SpawnObstacle");
        }
    }
    IEnumerator SpawnObstacle()
    {
        spawning = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(MINTObstacle, MAXTObstacle));
        Vector2 finalposition = new Vector2(Random.Range(3,7), Random.Range(pos.position.y - 6f, pos.position.y - 6f));
        Instantiate(Obstacle[Random.Range(0, Obstacle.Length)], finalposition, Quaternion.identity);
        spawning = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a 2d map of all the possible locations a object can spawn, then when the object spawns mark it on the map, once the object is off screen remove it from the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is some kind of bounding box around each obstacle that represents the "padding" that you want around that obstacle, where no other can be placed. You might use a primitive collider for this purpose.

When you create a new obstacle at a random position, you could check to see if its "padding" collides with another obstacle's "padding", and if so, re-calculate the random position.

One issue I foresee if if you have a very crowded space, this check might have to be re-done many many times before a valid location is found. You may want to limit the number of checks it can do, and if it doesn't find a valid spot it just doesn't spawn the object after 20 tries or so.

Comment: yeha, i think so, i wiill try!